# Google analytics API:Two daterange

Tags: python

I'm using Google analytics API.
I want to compare the data of TWO daterange.
So I use pandas.
But I don't know how to handle multiple variables by applymap().

```
def get_report(analytics):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(body={'reportRequests': [{'viewId': 
VIEW_ID,'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-02-01', 'endDate': '2018-02-28'},{'startDate': '2018-01-01', 'endDate': '2018-01-31'}], 'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'}],'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:entrances'},{'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'}, {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},{'expression': 'ga:exitRate'}]}]}).execute()

def parse_data(response):
    reports = response['reports'][0]
    columnHeader = reports['columnHeader']['dimensions']
    metricHeader = reports['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']

    columns = columnHeader
    for metric in metricHeader:
        columns.append(metric['name'])

    data = json_normalize(reports['data']['rows'])
    data_dimensions = pd.DataFrame(data['dimensions'].tolist())
    data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data['metrics'].tolist())
    data_metrics = data_metrics.applymap(lambda x: x['values'])
    data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data_metrics[0].tolist())

    global result
    result = pd.concat([data_dimensions, data_metrics], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    result.columns = columns

    return result
```

Someone knows well means?
Please help me.